# Data Scaling issue using Python Keras multi_gpu_model with LSTM / GRU to predict Timeseries data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu, lstm

There appears to be an data scaling issue with python keras LSTM / GRU layers with `multi_gpu_model` for machine learning.

When I use a single GPU, the predictions work correctly matching the sinusoidal data in the script below. See image labeled "1 GPU".

[1 GPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCad4.png)

When I use multiple GPUs, the inverse transforms of both the training and test data return results that cluster around the lows of the original data See image labeled "4 GPUs".

[4 GPUs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADpPa.png)

It appears to be a bug, or the `multi_gpu_model` documentation isn't complete with a caveat to cover this specific case.

Is this:

1. a bug?
2. a case where I'm missing a multiplier that should be used
   when `multi_gpu_model` is used?
3. an example where the
   `multi_gpu_model` documentation isn't complete with a
   caveat to cover this specific case?
4. the result of flaw(s) in my code?

---

Versions

```
Keras                   2.2.4  
Keras-Applications      1.0.6  
Keras-Preprocessing     1.0.5  
tensorboard             1.12.0 
tensorflow-gpu          1.12.0
```

GPUs

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.79       Driver Version: 410.79       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 107...  Off  | 00000000:08:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   42C    P0    36W / 180W |      0MiB /  8119MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 107...  Off  | 00000000:09:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 36%   48C    P0    37W / 180W |      0MiB /  8119MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX 107...  Off  | 00000000:41:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 34%   44C    P0    34W / 180W |      0MiB /  8119MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce GTX 107...  Off  | 00000000:42:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 31%   42C    P0    32W / 180W |      0MiB /  8112MiB |      5%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Script - (Same results when using GRU)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""LSTM for sinusoidal data problem with regression framing.

Based on:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

"""

# Standard imports
import argparse
import math

# PIP3 imports
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import DataFrame
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model

import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)

def main():
    # fix random seed for reproducibility
    numpy.random.seed(7)

    # Get CLI arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--gpus',
        help='Number of GPUs to use.',
        type=int, default=1)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    gpus = args.gpus

    # load the dataset
    dataframe = DataFrame(
        [0.00000, 5.99000, 11.92016, 17.73121, 23.36510, 28.76553, 33.87855,
         38.65306, 43.04137, 46.99961, 50.48826, 53.47244, 55.92235, 57.81349,
         59.12698, 59.84970, 59.97442, 59.49989, 58.43086, 56.77801, 54.55785,
         51.79256, 48.50978, 44.74231, 40.52779, 35.90833, 30.93008, 25.64279,
         20.09929, 14.35496, 8.46720, 2.49484, -3.50245, -9.46474, -15.33247,
         -21.04699, -26.55123, -31.79017, -36.71147, -41.26597, -45.40815,
         -49.09663, -52.29455, -54.96996, -57.09612, -58.65181, -59.62146,
         -59.99540, -59.76988, -58.94716, -57.53546, -55.54888, -53.00728,
         -49.93605, -46.36587, -42.33242, -37.87600, -33.04113, -27.87613,
         -22.43260, -16.76493, -10.92975, -4.98536, 1.00883, 6.99295, 12.90720,
         18.69248, 24.29100, 29.64680, 34.70639, 39.41920, 43.73814, 47.62007,
         51.02620, 53.92249, 56.28000, 58.07518, 59.29009, 59.91260, 59.93648,
         59.36149, 58.19339, 56.44383, 54.13031, 51.27593, 47.90923, 44.06383,
         39.77815, 35.09503, 30.06125, 24.72711, 19.14590, 13.37339, 7.46727,
         1.48653, -4.50907, -10.45961, -16.30564, -21.98875, -27.45215,
         -32.64127, -37.50424, -41.99248, -46.06115, -49.66959, -52.78175,
         -55.36653, -57.39810, -58.85617, -59.72618, -59.99941, -59.67316,
         -58.75066, -57.24115, -55.15971, -52.52713, -49.36972, -45.71902,
         -41.61151, -37.08823, -32.19438, -26.97885, -21.49376, -15.79391,
         -9.93625, -3.97931, 2.01738, 7.99392, 13.89059, 19.64847, 25.21002,
         30.51969, 35.52441, 40.17419, 44.42255, 48.22707, 51.54971, 54.35728,
         56.62174, 58.32045, 59.43644, 59.95856, 59.88160, 59.20632, 57.93947,
         56.09370, 53.68747, 50.74481, 47.29512, 43.37288, 39.01727, 34.27181,
         29.18392, 23.80443, 18.18710, 12.38805, 6.46522, 0.47779, -5.51441,
         -11.45151])
    dataset = dataframe.values
    dataset = dataset.astype('float32')

    # normalize the dataset
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

    # split into train and test sets
    train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
    test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
    train, test = dataset[0:train_size, :], dataset[train_size:len(dataset), :]

    # reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
    look_back = 1
    trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
    testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)

    # reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
    trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
    testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))

    # create and fit the LSTM network
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        serial_model = Sequential()
    serial_model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
    serial_model.add(Dense(1))
    if gpus == 1:
        parallel_model = serial_model
    else:
        parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(
            serial_model,
            cpu_relocation=True,
            gpus=gpus)
    parallel_model.compile(
        loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    parallel_model.fit(
        trainX, trainY,
        epochs=100,
        batch_size=int(dataset.size * gpus / 20),
        verbose=2)

    # make predictions
    if gpus == 1:
        trainPredict = parallel_model.predict(trainX)
        testPredict = parallel_model.predict(testX)
    else:
        trainPredict = serial_model.predict(trainX)
        testPredict = serial_model.predict(testX)

    # invert predictions
    trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
    trainY = scaler.inverse_transform([trainY])
    testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
    testY = scaler.inverse_transform([testY])

    # calculate root mean squared error
    trainScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY[0], trainPredict[:, 0]))
    print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore))
    testScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY[0], testPredict[:, 0]))
    print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))

    # shift train predictions for plotting
    trainPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
    trainPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
    trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back, :] = trainPredict

    # shift test predictions for plotting
    testPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
    testPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
    testPredictPlot[
        len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:len(dataset)-1, :] = testPredict

    # plot baseline and predictions
    plt.plot(scaler.inverse_transform(dataset), label='Complete Data')
    plt.plot(trainPredictPlot, label='Training Data')
    plt.plot(testPredictPlot, label='Prediction Data')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.title('Using {} GPUs'.format(gpus))
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I thought it may have something to do with the Sequential model, but I get the same results when I replace:

```
# create and fit the LSTM network
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    serial_model = Sequential()
serial_model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
serial_model.add(Dense(1))
```

with:

```
from keras import Model, Input

# Create layers for model
x_tensor = Input(shape=(1, look_back))
layer_1 = LSTM(4)(x_tensor)
y_tensor = Dense(1)(layer_1)

# Create and fit the LSTM network
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    serial_model = Model(inputs=x_tensor, outputs=y_tensor)
```

I now think it has something to do with the way `multi_gpu_model` splits the timeseries data across the GPUs. The RMSE error rates are noticeably different.

**RMSE - I GPU**

```
Train Score: 4.49 RMSE
Test Score: 4.79 RMSE
```

**RMSE - 4 GPUs**

```
Train Score: 76.54 RMSE
Test Score: 77.55 RMSE
```

Comment: I've opened a case with the Keras team which hopefully will resolve the issue https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11953

Answer (score 0):

In the tensorflow2.0 documentation mentioned that multi_gpu functionality is deprecated. The best practice for using multiple GPUs is to use tf.distribute.Strategy. I changed a little bit your code, wherein my two GPUs, it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""LSTM for sinusoidal data problem with regression framing.

Based on:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

"""

# Standard imports
import argparse
import math

# PIP3 imports
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from pandas import DataFrame
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model

import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)

def main():
    # fix random seed for reproducibility
    numpy.random.seed(7)

    # Get CLI arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--gpus',
        help='Number of GPUs to use.',
        type=int, default=1)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    gpus = args.gpus

    # load the dataset
    dataframe = DataFrame(
        [0.00000, 5.99000, 11.92016, 17.73121, 23.36510, 28.76553, 33.87855,
         38.65306, 43.04137, 46.99961, 50.48826, 53.47244, 55.92235, 57.81349,
         59.12698, 59.84970, 59.97442, 59.49989, 58.43086, 56.77801, 54.55785,
         51.79256, 48.50978, 44.74231, 40.52779, 35.90833, 30.93008, 25.64279,
         20.09929, 14.35496, 8.46720, 2.49484, -3.50245, -9.46474, -15.33247,
         -21.04699, -26.55123, -31.79017, -36.71147, -41.26597, -45.40815,
         -49.09663, -52.29455, -54.96996, -57.09612, -58.65181, -59.62146,
         -59.99540, -59.76988, -58.94716, -57.53546, -55.54888, -53.00728,
         -49.93605, -46.36587, -42.33242, -37.87600, -33.04113, -27.87613,
         -22.43260, -16.76493, -10.92975, -4.98536, 1.00883, 6.99295, 12.90720,
         18.69248, 24.29100, 29.64680, 34.70639, 39.41920, 43.73814, 47.62007,
         51.02620, 53.92249, 56.28000, 58.07518, 59.29009, 59.91260, 59.93648,
         59.36149, 58.19339, 56.44383, 54.13031, 51.27593, 47.90923, 44.06383,
         39.77815, 35.09503, 30.06125, 24.72711, 19.14590, 13.37339, 7.46727,
         1.48653, -4.50907, -10.45961, -16.30564, -21.98875, -27.45215,
         -32.64127, -37.50424, -41.99248, -46.06115, -49.66959, -52.78175,
         -55.36653, -57.39810, -58.85617, -59.72618, -59.99941, -59.67316,
         -58.75066, -57.24115, -55.15971, -52.52713, -49.36972, -45.71902,
         -41.61151, -37.08823, -32.19438, -26.97885, -21.49376, -15.79391,
         -9.93625, -3.97931, 2.01738, 7.99392, 13.89059, 19.64847, 25.21002,
         30.51969, 35.52441, 40.17419, 44.42255, 48.22707, 51.54971, 54.35728,
         56.62174, 58.32045, 59.43644, 59.95856, 59.88160, 59.20632, 57.93947,
         56.09370, 53.68747, 50.74481, 47.29512, 43.37288, 39.01727, 34.27181,
         29.18392, 23.80443, 18.18710, 12.38805, 6.46522, 0.47779, -5.51441,
         -11.45151])
    dataset = dataframe.values
    dataset = dataset.astype('float32')

    # normalize the dataset
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

    # split into train and test sets
    train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
    test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
    train, test = dataset[0:train_size, :], dataset[train_size:len(dataset), :]

    # reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
    look_back = 1
    trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
    testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)

    # reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
    trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
    testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))

    # create and fit the LSTM network
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

    if gpus == 1:
        model = tf.keras.Sequential()
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
        model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    else:
        strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/gpu:0", "/gpu:1"])
        print('Number of devices: {}'.format(strategy.num_replicas_in_sync))

        # Define the model
        with strategy.scope():
            model = tf.keras.Sequential()
            model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
            model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
            model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

            # inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1, look_back))
            # lstm_layer = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4)(inputs)
            # outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(lstm_layer)
            # model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
            # model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

    model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=4, verbose=2)

    trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
    testPredict = model.predict(testX)

    # invert predictions
    trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
    trainY = scaler.inverse_transform([trainY])
    testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
    testY = scaler.inverse_transform([testY])

    # calculate root mean squared error
    trainScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY[0], trainPredict[:, 0]))
    print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore))
    testScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY[0], testPredict[:, 0]))
    print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))

    # shift train predictions for plotting
    trainPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
    trainPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
    trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back, :] = trainPredict

    # shift test predictions for plotting
    testPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
    testPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
    testPredictPlot[
        len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:len(dataset)-1, :] = testPredict

    # plot baseline and predictions
    plt.plot(scaler.inverse_transform(dataset), label='Complete Data')
    plt.plot(trainPredictPlot, label='Training Data')
    plt.plot(testPredictPlot, label='Prediction Data')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.title('Using {} GPUs'.format(gpus))
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```